# Is there anything like .\scripts\autolinking.gradle when a react-native project is created

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, android-virtual-device, npx

I tried creating a react-native project with the command : npx react-native init VReact but it only downloads the node_modules folder, a package.json and a package-lock file. Nothing else. I did npx create-react-native-app VReact and it seemed to work fine. I get an error whenever I run react-native run-android (I do it from VReact directory as i've learnt), the error:

> 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Same for react-native init VReact (without npx)

npx react-native run-android works but yet another error.

My AVD never showed my App.js even though I run it first before doing any other thing.

I installed react-native-cli globally but create-new-react-app VReact requires me to install expo globally. I did but i'm still stuck.

What i've also tried:

1. Deleted the whole project and started all over
2. Created a new virtual device

Why can't I run commands unless I use "npx" prefix?

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'VReact'.
> Could not read script 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1586]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\ReactNative\VReact>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 945 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'VReact'.
> Could not read script 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'VReact'.
> Could not read script 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s

    at makeError (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

C:\ReactNative\VReact>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 945 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'VReact'.
> Could not read script 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'VReact'.
> Could not read script 'C:\ReactNative\VReact\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

    at makeError (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\ReactNative\VReact\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

C:\ReactNative\VReact>
```

#settings.gradle file content

```
rootProject.name = 'TwoShell'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
includeBuild(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native-gradle-plugin/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile())

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
  include(":ReactAndroid")
  project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../ReactAndroid");
}
```